# Why do I need to cast the result of copy.deepcopy?

Tags: python, deep-copy, type-hinting, mypy

Here's my attempt at overloading `__deepcopy__` for a toy class

```
import copy
from typing import Dict

class Foo:
    pass


class Bar:
    def __init__(self, foo: Foo):
        self._foo = foo

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo: Dict[int, object]) -> Bar:
        return Bar(copy.deepcopy(self._foo, memo))
```

However, mypy complains with

> error: Argument 1 to "Bar" has incompatible type "object"; expected "Foo"

I can fix it by casting the result of `copy.deepcopy`

```
from typing import cast

    ...
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo: Dict[int, object]) -> Bar:
        return Bar(cast(Foo, copy.deepcopy(self._foo, memo)))
```

but that feels unnecessary. Am I doing this right?

edit: I've just dug into the [typeshed repo](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/copy.pyi#L9), and found they do type as

```
_T = TypeVar("_T")

def deepcopy(
    x: _T, memo: Optional[Dict[int, Any]] = ..., _nil: Any = ...
) -> _T: ...
```

which I would have thought should prevent the need for `cast`

Comment: @Carcigenicate oh so it might be inferring `self._foo` as `object`? That's unfortunate

Answer (score 2):

You are right that the type signature for `deepcopy`

```
def deepcopy(x: _T, memo: Optional[Dict[int, Any]] = ..., _nil: Any = ...) -> _T: ...
```

would avoid having to cast the result.

However, this was fixed in https://github.com/python/typeshed/pull/4828 just 5 days ago.

So, mypy is not using that type definitions, instead they are using the signature:

```
def deepcopy(x: _T, memo: Optional[Dict[int, _T]] = ..., _nil: Any = ...) -> _T: ...
```

You have 3 options:

- Keep using the cast in the meantime
- Clone the latest version of `typeshed` and use the config option [`custom_typeshed_dir`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-custom_typeshed_dir)
- Change the type of your `memo` to `Dict[int, Foo]`